# at com.future.vpn.Activities.MainActivity.onStart(MainActivity.java:186)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

2021-08-14 19:43:53.129 8682-8682/com.future.vpn E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.future.vpn, PID: 8682
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
at com.future.vpn.Activities.MainActivity.onStart(MainActivity.java:186)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1435)
at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:8024)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStartActivity(ActivityThread.java:3475)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence(TransactionExecutor.java:221)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath(TransactionExecutor.java:201)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:173)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
2021-08-14 19:43:53.186 8682-8682/com.future.vpn I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 8682 SIG: 9

Answer (score 0):

This is a NullPointerException, you are passing a null value. Place break points on the sections that contain variables/values then run it (using the Debug feature on). This will show you:

- which value you are getting a null response from. Once achieved, now check:
- how your code structure is (global and local scopes). This might be an issue as the scope of the variable assignment determines whether your variable has a value or it doesn't.

Start from there, and it would be best you share the code snippet to make it more elaborate.

Comment: Thank you Mr.Mark for the edits, apologies for the shorthand writing.

Comment: Please help me to solve this issue app crashes on start

Comment: Kindly share your code, it would make it easier...

Answer (score 0):

In `onstart()` Method you have a string that is not initialized and you are comparing it with another string that's why you are getting this error.
first, initialize string then compare with another string

Comment: Can you please help me short out this issue ?

Comment: @samy add code part in question so i can help you